# How can I get a result in SQL that shows summary?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a sample table below:

```
FACE   SHAP
----   ----
new1   oblq
new2   oblq
new3   rond
new5   sqre
new2   rond
new1   oblq
new2   oblq
new3   rond
new2   rond
new3   oblq
```

and I want it to be shown like this:

```
FACE   oblq   rond   sqre
----   ----   ----   ----
new1      2      0      0
new2      2      2      0
new3      2      2      0
new5      0      0      1
```

How can i get the results using SQL query? thanks in advance..

Comment: Shouldn't the `new3` count of `oblq` be 1 not 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`PIVOT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Face
                             ORDER BY Shap) RN
  FROM tablename
) AS p
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(RN)
  FOR SHAP IN(oblq,   rond,   sqre)
) AS p;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fee1/4)

This will give you:

```
| FACE | OBLQ | ROND | SQRE |
-----------------------------
| new1 |    2 |    0 |    0 |
| new2 |    2 |    2 |    0 |
| new3 |    1 |    2 |    0 |
| new5 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
```

---

For multiple values `SHAP` and you don't need to write them manually, you have to do this dynamically using dynamic SQL. Like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(SHAP)
                      FROM tablename                      
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
SET @query = 
' SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Face
                               ORDER BY Shap) RN
   FROM tablename
) AS p
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(RN)
   FOR SHAP IN( ' + @cols + ')
) AS p;';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fee1/5)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
select FACE,
       SUM(Case When SHAP = 'oblq' then 1 Else 0 End )AS oblq,
       SUM(Case When SHAP = 'rond' then 1 Else 0 End )AS rond,
       SUM(Case When SHAP = 'sqre' then 1 Else 0 End )AS sqre
From yourTable
Group by FACE
```